# How mock a class with a custom annotation using Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, annotations, mockito

I'm writing a unit test for CatalogFacade class; the class is like this:

```
public class CatalogFacade{
    @Inject
    @Shallow //custom annotation
    private ITServiceMapper servMapper;
    @Inject
    @Complete //custom annotation
    private ITServiceMapper dServMapper;

    @Override
    public ITService getITService(String serviceCode) {

        ITService a = dServMapper.method();
        return a;
    }

}
```

and I have written the unit test in this way:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CatalogFacadeTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private CatalogFacade facade;
    @Mock
    private ITServiceMapper servMapperMock;
    @Mock
    private ITServiceMapper dServMapperMock;

    @Test
    public void getITService() {
        /* prepare value objects */
        ITService dtoMock= Mockito.mock(ITService.class);

        /* Given some preconditions (Arrange) */
        given(dServMapperMock.modelToDto(entityMock)).willReturn(dtoMock);

        /* When an action occurs (Act) */
        ITService service= facade.getITService("AMS-SA-0001");

        /* Then verify the output (Assert) */
        assertThat(dtoMock.getItServiceCode(),
        is(equalTo(service.getItServiceCode())));
    }
}
```

but the test throws a NullPointeException because when dServMapperMock.method() is called, dservMapperMock is null, so I think it's not mocked correctly...

I think the problem could be the class ITServiceMapper has custom annotation and I'm not able to mock it.

How can I mock this class?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primary reason this isn't working is because you have more than one instance of `ITServiceMapper` in your class(CatalogFacade).

Mockito(specifically @InjectMocks) has some issues in these scenarios. Easiest way to fix this is by assisting Mockito with the name attribute like this

```
@Mock(name = "servMapper")
private ITServiceMapper servMapper;

@Mock(name = "dServMapper")
private ITServiceMapper dServMapperMock;
```

This is one of the reason why Constructor injection is always better than Field injection.
Check [this](http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/) article for more info